# add second page with figure to existing pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, reportlab

Can you help me please, how to add pylab plt, to second page of my pdf. I have next code for text, so the first page of my report will be text, on second page i wan't to insert the plot. How can i add second page and save `plt.savefig("my.pdf")` to the second page of my pdf file?

```
c = canvas.Canvas('my.pdf', pagesize=landscape(letter))
c.setFont('Helvetica', 35, leading=None)
c.drawCentredString(415,500, "Name")
c.setFont('Helvetica', 34, leading=None)
c.drawCentredString(415,440, "Surname")
c.setFont('Helvetica',24, leading=None)
c.drawCentredString(415,395, "Igorj Borin")
c.setFont('Helvetica-Bold', 16, leading=None)
c.drawCentredString(415,350, "Vasja pupkin")
c.setFont('Helvetica-Bold', 20, leading=None)
c.drawCentredString(415,310, strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
c.showPage()
c.save()

plt.savefig("my.pdf")
```

Comment: 1) You're using Reportlab, I assume? 2) Is it important to have your picture `my.pdf` attached as a pdf? Or could it be e.g. a png image that you import in your pdf?

Comment: Yes, i'm using Reportlab, Pyplot, Matplotlib.It's a simple chart, i think it's can be png

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bitmap image, like png, jpg, gif, bmp (oh dear..), you could add the following lines in front of your call to `c.save()`:

```
from reportlab.lib.units import inch, cm  # 72 dpi -> inch = 72 
c.drawImage('my.png',2.5*cm, 5*cm, 4*inch, 3*inch) # parameters: filename, spacing from left and bottom, with width and height
```

Reportlab doesn't seem to handle vector images well, even with PIL installed, it will result in an `IOError: cannot identify image file` if you use it on the image exported as pdf.
However, you could e.g. use ghostscript to merge pdfs, regardless of their content. But then you won't have the typical reportlab styling.

Comment: This ok, but when i save my graph to .png, the image quality not so good, when i save this graph as pdf( Maybe you can tell me how to improve the quality of image? i Need to place full size graph to the center of my PDF page.

Comment: @JelenaKrasnakova When you save your image as a png with matplotlib, there is an option to change the dpi (dots per inch). By default, it is quite low (60-100). For publications, you might want to consider increasing this to 600dpi. `plt.savefig("my.pdf", dpi=600)` This will improve the quality.